# Using fb.ui send method to send link with referal id

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using a fb.ui send method to allow user to share a link through Facebook. (eg http://example.com/affiliateid=myuseraffiliateid)
My problem is that the og:url of the shared page doesn't have this parameter, and og:url always take precedence.

Using the Facebook Send button, I'm able to send a fb_ref parameter, so the shared url is http://example.com/fb_ref=myuseraffiliateid. This solution is OK for me, I just have to set affiliate_id = fb_ref in the server side code of my page.
However, I can't use the facebook send button as I need to prepopulate the "to" field.

In short, what I'm looking for is a way to add this fb_ref attribute to the link sent.

Maybe code is easier to understand than plain text, so here it is:

Here's is the code of the JS call to the send dialog:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'send',
  link: "http://www.example.com/affiliateid/myuseraffiliateid",
  to: [11111,22222,33333],
});
```

With this method, the resultig shared link is equal to the og:url specified (ie http://www.example.com).

And here is the fb:send button which actually works, but without the "to" prepopulated

```
<fb:send 
  href="http://www.example.com" 
  ref="myuseraffiliateid"
></fb:send>
```

Now, since we've specified a "ref" attribute to the send button, the shared link is "http://www.example.com/fb_ref=myuseraffiliateid".

What I need is to reproduce the ref attribute using fb.ui...

Comment: Instead of http://www.example.com/affiliateid=myuseraffiliateid can you have your URl structure as http://www.example.com/?affiliateid=myuseraffiliateid ? in which case your og:url without the affiliateid should work fine..

Comment: Oops, I've been lying: here is the actual url structure : example.com/affiliateid/myuseraffiliateid. I'll try your answer right now, by replacing this URL by "example.com/?fb_send=myaffiliateid" (it's just easier for me to do it this way, instead of ?affiliate_id...

Comment: YEAAAHHHH!!!! Thank you dude :) Can you add your comment as a proper answer so I can mark it resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally avoided this issue by using a dynamic og:url in the landing page of the shared link. That's annoying, since I can't count the number of shared links :(

Answer (score 3):

Instead of "example.com/affiliateid=myuseraffiliateid" change your URl structure to "example.com/?affiliateid=myuseraffiliateid".

By doing this, the og:url of the page should remain stable (and consistent with what FB expects) and hence it should work fine.

Comment: In fact, it works only with differents domain names: if I share a link "examle1.com" from "example.com", it's OK. If i share a link "example.com" through "example.com:, it doesn't. WTF?!. This Facebook thing is driving me crazy...

Comment: Does example.com contain the og:url or does example1.com or both?

Comment: In my case, example1.com contains og:url example1.com, but is not accessible to Facebook anyway. Example.com has og:url in example.com